# Calling overriding constructor and base in C#

Tags: c#

How can I fix this error without redundant code?

```
    public Comparison2(decimal number1, decimal number2) : base()
    {
        this.Number1 = number1;
        this.Number2 = number2;
    }

    public Comparison2(decimal number1, decimal number2, int problemNumber, int subject, int seconds)
        : this(number1, number2), base(problemNumber, subject, seconds) { }
```

Comment: Perhaps you'd elaborate on the particular piece of redundancy you'd like to fix...? (I assume you want to be able to both call the base constructor as well another constructor within the same class)

Comment: You can't say 'of course' when you post code with no explanation.

Comment: @Rob Sorry for my bad English, I meant to say something like "you're right" or "that's the point".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your only choice is to do this:

```
public Comparison2(decimal number1, decimal number2) : base()
{
    this.SetNumbers(number1, number2);
}

public Comparison2(decimal number1, decimal number2, int problemNumber,
        int subject, int seconds)
    : base(problemNumber, subject, seconds)
{
    this.SetNumbers(number1, number2);
}

private void SetNumbers(decimal number1, decimal number2)
{
    this.Number1 = number1;
    this.Number2 = number2;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, writing the same code multiple times is the best option, especially when it's this simple.

But if you really want to avoid repeating yourself or if your actual code is more complicated, you could just create a method to contain the code. One disadvantage to this approach is that you can't set `readonly` fields outside constructors.